# заполнение combobox через enum .net

Tags: .net

Пытаюсь заполнить свой `cb_StatusTicketBenutzer` через `enum`

сам `enum`

```
Public Enum enStatus
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Neu
        ''' </summary>
        N
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Vorbereitet 
        ''' </summary>
        V
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Laufend 
        ''' </summary>
        L
End Enum

<Extension>
    Public Function Text(ByVal pi_Status As enStatus) As String
        Select Case pi_Status
            Case enStatus.N
                Return "Neu"
            Case enStatus.V
                Return "Vorbereitet"
            Case enStatus.L
                Return "Laufend"
End Function
```

И собсвенно заполняю его и выберию текущий:

```
cb_StatusTicketBenutzer.DataSource = [Enum].GetValues(GetType(enStatus))

cb_StatusTicketBenutzer.SelectedItem = m_clsTicket.Status
```

Все что показывает, только букву N/V/L.. Но не полное название

Comment: Может быть `myenum.ENUMVALUE.ToString()` ? Через селектор некрасиво как то..

Comment: Можно сделать нечто подобное с помощью атрибута `Description`. Подробная информация как это сделать - [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/479410/6468198)